# SQL Server 2017をWindows 10のスタンドアロン環境で商用運用する場合どのエディションが適切でしょうか？

Tags: windows, sql-server

Windows 10のスタンドアロン環境※でSQL Server 2017を商用運用する場合、どのエディションが適切でしょうか？Expressも含めて検討しております。

※スタンドアロン環境のため、SQL ServerをインストールしたWindows10に対して、別のクライアント端末からアクセスすることはありません。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

技術的には[SQL Server のエディション](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#includessnoversionincludesssnoversion-mdmd-editions)と[OS の互換性](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/sql-server/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-for-installing-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#TOP_Principal)からほとんど絞り込まれます。

- Developer
  開発もしくはテスト目的でのみ使用可能なため、商用運用には使用できません。
- Enterprise
  Enterprise / Developerでしか提供されていない機能を使う場合、Enterpriseが必須となります。ただし、Windows 10では動作しません。
- Web
  Windows 10では動作しません。
- Standard
  サポートが必要であればStandardとなります。
- Express
  [スケールの制限](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2017?view=sql-server-ver15#Cross-BoxScaleLimits)内で、サポートが必要なければExpressとなります。

後はライセンス条項と提供者側の判断となります。

> スケールの制限についてですが、Expressの「1ソケットまたは 4 コアのいずれか小さいほうに制限」というのは、ExpressをインストールするPCに搭載しているCPUが1物理CPUまたは4コアを超えてはいけないという意味でしょうか？

スケールの制限は１つのインスタンスで使用可能な最大量が記載されています。例えば、10GB以上のディスクサイズを持つPCへのインストールが禁止されていることを意味するわけではありません。

---

[Windows 10のライセンス条項](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Useterms/Retail/Windows/10/UseTerms_Retail_Windows_10_japanese.htm)に違反していているように見受けられます。

> **2. インストールおよび使用権。**
>   **c.制限。** 製造業者またはインストール業者、およびマイクロソフトは、本ライセンス条項において明示的に許諾されていない権利 (知的財産に関する法律に基づく権利など) をすべて留保します。たとえば、このライセンスは、次の行為に関してお客様にいかなる権利も与えるものではなく、お客様は次の行為を行うことはできません。
>
> (v) 本ソフトウェアをサーバーソフトウェアとして使用することもしくは商業的ホスティング用に使用すること、本ソフトウェアをネットワークを介して複数のユーザーが同時に使用できるようにすること、本ソフトウェアをサーバーにインストールしてユーザーがリモートアクセスできるようにすること、または本ソフトウェアをリモートユーザーのみが使用する目的でデバイスにインストールすること。

Comment: スタンドアロン環境のため、別のクライアント端末からWindows10にインストールしているSQL Serverにアクセスすることはありません。このため、サーバソフトウェアとして使用することには当たらない認識なのですが。間違ってますでしょうか。

Comment: @mame 利用方法が明確にならないことには本題の質問にも答えられないと思います。コメントされた内容は質問文にも記載されるべきかなと。それと、スタンドアロンであればサーバーでないと言えるのかについては分かりませんでした。この辺りはMicrosoft社が判断することになるかなと。

Comment: @mame ソフトウェアライセンスに関する質問をどう扱うかは、メタの投稿も参考にしてください。 - [ソフトウェアライセンスに関する質問をどう考えるか](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1541/3060) / 特に**商用**ライセンスに関わる部分については、提供元にご自身で確認していただくのが確実かと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。提供元にも確認してみます。

Comment: @sayuri スケールの制限についてですが、Expressの「1ソケットまたは 4 コアのいずれか小さいほうに制限」というのは、ExpressをインストールするPCに搭載しているCPUが1物理CPUまたは4コアを超えてはいけないという意味でしょうか？例えば、1CPUで8コアのPCは、Expressを使用できない。